# VBA: Making specific text bold or italic

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to the macro. I am looking forward for the code for printing some part of string in italic and rest in bold.

e.g.

> Hi ***There***, congratulation for new **assignment**.

I am able to print the entire string in either bold or in Italic but not able to find the code which can fulfil my requirement.

Also splitting the text in to the dummy variable and joining those post applying the formatting seems to be a lengthy option.

Comment: Look into the Range.Character() function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel vba set bold specific text of string into the cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644566/excel-vba-set-bold-specific-text-of-string-into-the-cell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Play around with this, it will do what you used for your example.

```
Sub SetBoldAndItalicInCell()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Hi There, congratulation for new assignment."
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=3).Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
    ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=4, Length:=5).Font.FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
    ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=9, Length:=24).Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
    ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=33, Length:=11).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=44, Length:=1).Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
End Sub
```