# Making Certain Text Bold In Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am exporting an excel table into word using VBA. The word document has one bookmark. The code is such that first it writes the TYPE as the heading and then write all the description under that TYPE. I want the headings to be bold and formatted. I have the following code but it does not work. If anyone could suggest something.

```
If Dir(strPath & "\" & strFileName) <> "" Then

    'Word Document open
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWDApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If objWDApp Is Nothing Then Set objWDApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With objWDApp
        .Visible = True 'Or True, if Word is to be indicated
        .Documents.Open (strPath & "\" & strFileName)
        Set objRng = objWDApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark").Range

        .Styles.Add ("Heading")
        .Styles.Add ("Text")

        With .Styles("Heading").Font

            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 12
            .Bold = True
            .Underline = True
        End With

        With .Styles("Text").Font

            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 10
            .Bold = False
            .Underline = False
        End With


    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    i = Start_Cell 
    idx(1) = i 
    n = 2 
    Do ' Search for first empty cell in the table
        i = i + 1


        If i > Start_Cell + 1 And Cells(i, QB_Type).Value = Cells(i - 1, QB_Type) Then GoTo Loop1
        idx(n) = i
        n = n + 1
```

Loop1:

```
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, QB_Type).Value)


    idxEnd = i 
    idx(n) = 9999 

    i = Start_Cell
    n = 1 
    Do

        If i = idx(n) Then
            strTMP = vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Cells(idx(n), QB_Type).Value & vbNewLine 


                  With objWDApp

               '.Selection.Font.Bold = True 'Type Bold (Doesnt Functions!?)

               .Selection.Styles ("Heading") 'I tried this as well but not functioning...gives an error here that object does not support this property

                WriteToWord objRng, strTMP 'Text written
            End With
            n = n + 1 
        End If

        strTMP = vbNewLine & Cells(i, QB_Description).Value & vbNewLine 
        With objWDApp
          '  .Selection.Font.Bold = False 'Description Not bold (Not functioning!?)
          .Selection.Styles("Text") 'This is also not functioning

            WriteToWord objRng, strTMP 'Text written
        End With
        i = i + 1 'Arbeitspunktzähler erhöhen
    Loop Until i > idxEnd
```

`Public Sub WriteToWord(objRng, text)
    With objRng
        .InsertAfter text
    End With
End Sub`

Comment: Record a macro that selects the cells and sets the font the way you want. Stop the recording and view the macros, pick the one you recorded, and click the Edit button to see the code, and it will show you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: I don't have a computer near me so I can't test, but does having the parentheses around "Heading" cause the problem? Maybe remove them and try. VBA is picky about parentheses and method/property calls.

Comment: @TylerStandishMan No this does not help... the error is that the object does not support this property...I dont think it is to do with the paranthesis

Comment: @KenWhite By doing that, I select a range and then put that selection as Bold, which is not the case in my problem

Comment: Why can't you select a range (that includes all of the headings) and make them bold all at once?

Comment: If you see in the code, I am first searching for the Heading and then adding the description corresponding to that heading. I store that in a string called `strTMP` and now i want to format this string @KenWhite

Comment: @user3446714  if you could help

Comment: Can you reformat your question details to a completely reproducible state? WriteToWord I don't think is a build in function, you're referencing indexes we're not aware of, you provide snippets of code rather than a working method. If you're able to provide a simplified example of the problem, I may be able to help more.

Comment: ok.. I guess i understood the problem...I dont have a WrdDoc object in my code. Is it something that the `Style` property is supported by `WrdDoc` object and not by the `WrdApplication` object @TylerStandishMan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel vba set bold specific text of string into the cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644566/excel-vba-set-bold-specific-text-of-string-into-the-cell)

Answer (score 0):

Try `.Selection.Style.Name = "Heading"` from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834326.aspx)

**Edit 2**

The following code works as expected. You will need to modify it to fit your needs. I successfully added and then bolded text to an existing word document.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    '   Add a reference to Microsoft Word x.0 Object Library for early binding and syntax support
    Dim w As Word.Application
    If (w Is Nothing) Then Set w = New Word.Application

    Dim item As Word.Document, doc As Word.Document

    '   If the document is already open, just get a reference to it
    For Each item In w.Documents
        If (item.FullName = "C:\Path\To\Test.docx") Then
            Set doc = item
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    '   Else, open the document
    If (doc Is Nothing) Then Set doc = w.Documents.Open("C:\Path\To\Test.docx")

    '   Force change Word's default read-only/protected view
    doc.ActiveWindow.View = wdNormalView

    '   Delete the preexisting style to avoid an error of duplicate entry next time this is run
    '   Could also check if the style exists by iterating through all styles. Whichever method works for you
    doc.Styles.item("MyStyle").Delete
    doc.Styles.Add "MyStyle"

    With doc.Styles("MyStyle").Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
        .Bold = True
        .Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    End With

    '   Do your logic to put text where you need it
    doc.Range.InsertAfter "This is another Heading"

    '   Now find that same text you just added to the document, and bold it.
    With doc.Content.Find
        .Text = "This is another Heading"
        .Execute
        If (.Found) Then .Parent.Bold = True
    End With

    '   Make sure to dispose of the objects. This can cause issues when the macro gets out mid way, causing a file lock on the document
    doc.Close
    Set doc = Nothing
    w.Quit
    Set w = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image: Successful heading addition, in bold.]

By adding a reference to the object library, you can get intellisense support and compilation errors. It would help you determine earlier in development that Styles is not a valid property off the Word.Application object.

Comment: No, this also does not help...same error "Object Does Not Support This Property" @Tyler StandishMan

Comment: No...I tried this as well but of no help...again it says that Object does not support this property...I now cannot understand what the problem could be...Is this even possible or not ?

Comment: When i take the heading into the string `strTMP` and then use `doc.Selection.styles("heading")`...could it be that the range is not getting selected properly...?

Comment: Just a guess, since you haven't written the text to the document, it may be possible that the selection isn't anything. Also, doc.Selection is not a valid property. doc.Select is, but that doesn't seem like what you need.

Comment: See latest edits. I have successfully added text and bolded it. As I state in the answer, you will need to modify this to fit your needs, but it is a working template to work from.

Comment: I have a question...Why are you adding `My Style` when you are not using it anywhere ? Or have i misunderstood something ?

Comment: It still does not work as when i Need to add the description it says the string is too Long. I guess it depends on the text before the Bookmark in the word document. I have a text before the Bookmark. If I make this text bold, then the entire Contents exported become bold and if that text is normal, then the exported Contents are also normal.