# How to create a VBA formula that takes value and format from source cell

Tags: vba, excel, cell

In Excel's VBA I want to create a formula which both takes the value from the source cell and the format.

Currently I have:

```
Function formEq(cellRefd As Range) As Variant
    'thisBackCol = cellRefd.Interior.Color
    'With Application.Caller
    '    .Interior.Color = thisBackCol
    'End With
    formEq = cellRefd.Value
End Function`
```

This returns the current value of the cell. The parts that I have commented out return a `#VALUE` error in the cell. When uncommented it seems the colour of the reference is saved however the `Application.Caller` returns a 2023 Error. Does this mean that this is not returning the required Range object?

If so how do I get the range object that refers to the cell that the function is used? [obviously in order to set the colour to the source value].

Comment: Functions used as a UDF can only return a value - by themselves they cannot change anything else about the cells they're called from or other cells.

Comment: No other way around this? This seems like a massive, and very odd flaw in the application of VBA. There may be a good reason but it seems like an inconsistency in the way VBA treats the range object.

Comment: Could I call a separate sub that does this outside of the function? Or could I approach this from any other way? I'm guessing that this may be to do with the continuous updating that Excel does when the source cell changes value.

Comment: Here's an approach which seems to be usable, but you will need to test to make sure it doesn't have any unintended consequences:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet/23437280#23437280

Comment: @TimWilliams our link is great. A few notes, you can't use application caller presumably as that refers to other aspects of the sheet and a self-cell reference when used as in the example creates a circular reference which freezes Excel

Comment: If you need to refer to the calling cell (eg using `Application.Caller` or `Application.ThisCell`) then you can do that in the UDF itself, and pass the address as an argument to the code called using `Evaluate`.  To be safe it's best to have the UDF return a value to the calling cell, and not have the Evaluate'd code update that cell, or you might well end up in a loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120565/discussion-between-aer-and-tim-williams).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach showing how you can still use `ThisCell`:

```
Function CopyFormat(rngFrom, rngTo)
    rngTo.Interior.Color = rngFrom.Interior.Color
    rngTo.Font.Color = rngFrom.Font.Color
End Function



Function formEq(cellRefd As Range) As Variant
    cellRefd.Parent.Evaluate "CopyFormat(" & cellRefd.Address() & "," & _
                         Application.ThisCell.Address() & ")"
    formEq = cellRefd.Value
End Function
```

Comment: To use between worksheets and workbooks include that in `CopyFormat` as Worksheet and Workbook name objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I found to the above question using Tim William's [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet/23437280#23437280):

```
Function cq(thisCel As Range, srcCel As Range) As Variant
    thisCel.Parent.Evaluate "colorEq(" & srcCel.Address(False, False) _ 
    & "," & thisCel.Address(False, False) & ")"
    cq = srcCel.Value
End Function

Sub colorEq(srcCell, destCell)
    destCell.Interior.Color = srcCell.Interior.Color
End Sub
```

The `destCell` is just a cell reference to the cell in which the function is called.

The `interior.color` can be exchanged or added to with other formatting rules. Three extra points to note in this solution:

1. By keeping the value calculation in the formula this stops the possibility for circular referencing when it destCell refers to itself. If placed in the `sub` then it continually recalculates; and
2. If the format is only changed when the source value is changed, not the format as this is the only trigger for a UDF to run and thus change the format;
3. `Application.Caller` or `Application.ThisCell` cannot be integrated as when it refers to itself and returns a value for itself it triggers an infinite loop or "circular reference" error. If incorporated with an Address to create a string then this works though as per Tim William's answer.

Comment: Am I right, it isn't possible to use this technique to return a value and format this value directly? (e.g. generating text as return value of the function and directly format some words in this text with bold/italic/underline)
If this isn't possible, what would be the best workaround for this?

Comment: @Andy what do you mean by directly "directly"? I got this working 3 years ago, the color copied across, and the value was taken across as well. I used it for marking dodgy answers red and propagating that warning across spreadsheets.

Comment: With "directly" I mean, that the function is returning/building a larger string and I want to format some words of this string and return it to the cell where the formula is stored. 
Like: "This **is** a _test_ string." Or in other words: Returning text with some formatted words in it.

Comment: @Andy I see, haven't tried that. As you say, you can't format the string directly. This uses a source cell format and copies that across. You could try recording a macro and see how text is formatted directly and put that in the `Evaluate` as that is the only way to "sneak" in formatting.

Comment: Otherwise I'm not sure sorry

Comment: Basically it would work like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644566/excel-vba-set-bold-specific-text-of-string-into-the-cell but as it is a return-value, the solution (if it exists) must return the string AND then "trigger" the formatting sub. I'll try it together with https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel and a dynamic named range which covers the cells with the formula.

Comment: Remark: Worksheet_Change isn't working when the result of a formula is updating. It looks like Worksheet_Calculate should be used (see https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4618-excel-vba-run-macro-when-cell-formula-result-changes.html)