# How to convert part of a cell value to bold

Tags: string, vba, excel, vbscript

I have the below VBA code and `A` and `B` are holding some strings. I want to concatenate these values with some other strings and store the result in a different cell, but I want *only* the strings in `A` and `B` to be formatted as bold and the rest as normal text.

```
Set A = Worksheets("Mapping").Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber)
Set B = Worksheets("Mapping").Cells(rowNumber, 3)

' E.g.: A="currency", B="Small Int"

Worksheets("TestCases").Cells(i, 2) = "Verify the column " & A & " has same Data type " & B & " in code as well as Requirement document"
```

Expected output:

> Verify the column **currency** has same Data type **Small Int** in code   as well as Requirement document

Note: The values of `A` and `B` keep changing, so we cannot use the `Characters()` function.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't convert a variable to bold (I can't think of a single reason why you want to do that). However you can change the way you display the variable depending on where you want to display it. You may want to [display a text in bold in a `MsgBox`](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=vba%20msgbox%20bold) or [display a text in bold format in a cell](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=vba%20cell%20font%20bold). If you want any of those, Google is your friend and call help you with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel vba set bold specific text of string into the cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644566/excel-vba-set-bold-specific-text-of-string-into-the-cell)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have updated the question, could you please check it once again ?

Comment: You shouldn't change the question halfway through. People answer questions on here for rep, don't lead people on thinking they will get rep when you suddenly change the question once they have answered it.

Comment: @Someone if you're answering for rep you're answering for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @Lankymart lol would anyone be on this site without rep? I would recon not even 90% of the people on here would be here. Its a subconscious thing, I'm sure its the same for you if you think about it.

Comment: Why do you think yo can't use characters?
Characters(19, Len(A)).Font.Bold = True resp.
Characters(39 + Len(A), Len(B)).Font.Bold = True
could do it

Comment: @Storax Thanks buddy !!! I think i got my solutions .

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use the `Characters()` method - you just need to keep track of the length of the substrings. Personally, I would store the static strings in variables so that I can change them later without having to recalculate the indexes by hand:

```
' Untested

Set A = Worksheets("Mapping").Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber)
Set B = Worksheets("Mapping").Cells(rowNumber, 3)
Dim S1 = "Verify the column "
Dim S2 = " has same Data type "
Dim S3 = " in code as well as Requirement document"

With Worksheets("TestCases").Cells(i, 2)
    .Value = S1 & A & S2 & B & S3
    .Characters(Len(S1), Len(A)).Font.Bold
    .Characters(Len(S1)+Len(A)+Len(S2), Len(B)).Font.Bold
End With
```

Answer (score -1):

The function to change the font style is:

```
[Cells/Cell range].Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
```

Therefore something like might work:

```
Worksheets("Mapping").Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
```

You can also make things have underlines, strikethroughs etc... I found this really helpful blog post which goes through everything you should need to know:

http://software-solutions-online.com/excel-vba-formating-cells-and-ranges/#Jump4

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have updated the question, could you please check it once again ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should have searched for this information yourself... Nevertheless this is the code that you should use to convert some cell data to bold:

```
 Worksheets("Mapping").Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber).Font.Bold = True
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have updated the question, could you please check it once again ?

Comment: I have no more comments to do. As I said, you should not ask these kind of questions... It seems like you haven't done enough research before asking. 
If your problem is to convert a variable to bold, you should just do what you need to do and then convert it to bold in the way we said.